# Why is the angle of inclination not 9.5? How did you solve using trig ratios?

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

A mountain road rise $1m$ for ever $6m$ along he road.  Determine the angle of inclination, to the nearest tenth of a degree of the road.

**Answer:**

The angle of inclination = $9.6$
I got $9.5^\circ$  using $\tan$ ratio.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Interesting that we obtain different result. Do you happen to use an online calculator?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig ok, mystery solved, super thanks to Frenzy Li. I believed you meant $\arcsin$

Answer (score 2):

we should compute $\arcsin\left( \frac16 \right) \approx 9.594 \approx 9.6.$ as the distance is along the road.

Credit: Frenzy Li

[image]

Comment: I think that the 6 is the hypotenuse, not the adjacent side...  The OP is calculating $\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{6^{2}-1}}$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! I missed that.

Comment: Normally, I would expect that 6 is the horizontal displacement, but the wording of this specific question is "along the road".